# Why is "consistent nearest neighbour" Non-parametric?

Tags: machine-learning, nonparametric, k-nearest-neighbour

**Definition of "Consistent nearest neighbour"**, runs our usual KNN classifier
but instead of viewing k as a hyper-parameter it always sets k = ceil[log(n)].

So far, I looked-up many references and websites and researched on how to determine if a method is between parametric or non-parametric. I came up with below definitions,

> A parametric algorithm has a fixed number of parameters. In contrast, a non-parametric algorithm uses a flexible number of parameters, and the number of parameters often grows as it learns from more data.

From https://chemicalstatistician.wordpress.com/2014/01/14/machine-learning-lesson-of-the-day-parametric-vs-non-parametric-models/.

Moreover, I found,

> A parametric model, we have a finite number of parameters, and in nonparametric models, the number of parameters is (potentially) infinite.

From https://sebastianraschka.com/faq/docs/parametric_vs_nonparametric.html.

**My question is, why do we count it as a Non-parametric model**, while    the number of parameters can increase to infinity in the mentioned    method and it will gets more complicated by increasing test data?

Comment: Related question: [Why is “condensed nearest neighbour” Non-parametric?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/401302/why-is-condensed-nearest-neighbour-non-parametric).

Comment: Please notice that **condensed** nearest neighbour and **consistent** nearest neighbour are two different methods such one is Parametric and the other one is Non-parametric.

Comment: Whatever the distinction might be, @Richard is providing a useful comment because your other question is *identical* to this one apart from the substitution of "condensed" for "consistent."  We can therefore expect that answers to one will be highly relevant to the other--probably to the point of being exact duplicates.

Comment: @whuber, thank you for the feedback. With all due respect, I do not think so. Yet, if I found out that the answers are somehow similar, I would delete one of the questions.

Comment: @HosseinRahimi, I think the point is that once you understand the meanings of parametric vs non-p, you'll be able to see why any given algorithm would be classified as 1 or the other. So really, you just need your 1st question to clarify the distinction. If you're wondering something about how these knn variants work, you should edit your Q to clarify that. Even then, 1 question would probably be adequate to cover both *condensed* & *consistent*.