# Why is "condensed nearest neighbour" Parametric?

Tags: k-nearest-neighbour, nonparametric

**Definition of "condensed nearest neighbour"**, at training time it chooses the c
"best" training examples (where c is a hyper-parameter), and at test time uses the usual
KNN prediction but based only on these c training examples.

So far, I looked-up many references and websites and researched on how to determine if a method is between parametric or non-parametric. I came up with below definitions,

> A parametric algorithm has a fixed number of parameters. In contrast, a non-parametric algorithm uses a flexible number of parameters, and the number of parameters often grows as it learns from more data.

From https://chemicalstatistician.wordpress.com/2014/01/14/machine-learning-lesson-of-the-day-parametric-vs-non-parametric-models/.

Moreover, I found,

> A parametric model, we have a finite number of parameters, and in nonparametric models, the number of parameters is (potentially) infinite.

From https://sebastianraschka.com/faq/docs/parametric_vs_nonparametric.html.

**My question is, why do we count it as a Parametric model**?

Comment: Related question: [Why is “consistent nearest neighbour” Non-parametric?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/401296/why-is-consistent-nearest-neighbour-non-parametric).

Comment: Please notice that **condensed** nearest neighbour and **consistent** nearest neighbour are two different methods such one is Parametric and the other one is Non-parametric.